# Docusign promote integrator key from demo to live

Tags: docusignapi

I am currently trying to promote an integrator key from the demo environment to a live environment. I have read all of the documentation regarding this process and have had no issues up until this point. Currently, I have an integrator key in my demo environment which has passed review and I am trying to promote this key to my live environment. To do so, I am logging into my demo environment, selecting new admin experience, selecting APIs and Keys, selecting the "Actions" dropdown next to my key which has passed review, and then selecting "go live". After doing this, a terms and conditions popup comes up which I accept and then I am redirected to a login page. I understand from the documentation that my live environment login credentials are used here however I am unable to log in. I can use the same login credentials at na2.docusign.net/Member/MemberLogin.aspx and I am logged into my live admin account error just fine. I have also tried using the forgot password link on this popup in which I am successfully able to reset my password via a secret question. I then go back through the same process to get to the login popup after selecting my key to go live and again, I am unable to login. How can I overcome this as it is a time sensitive issue? I have also sent an e-mail, per the documentation, to go-live@docusign.com outlining this issue and have not yet received a response.

Note that my live account is a member of the administrator group. Are there other permissions that need to be set up that may be preventing me from completing this?

Answer (score 0):

Please resend your email to go-live@docusign.com

Please include the integration key, the account id for your demo account, and the account id for your production na2.docusign.net account.

Your account ids are shown in the drop-down by your name in the web tool's upper right hand corner, by your picture or glyph.

Please accept my apologies for these problems with the new Go-Live system.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with the DocuSign go live process. It has now been resolved. Please try again.