# docusign - getting "invalid_scope" while trying to promote integrator key from demo to Live account

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, apex

Salesforce - DocuSign integration via SOAP API:

From DocuSign Admin demo:

> I got the API transactions verified.
>
> I am trying to promote a integrator key from demo to Live account.
>
> Got a popup to enter Live credentials.
>
> But there is an message `invalid_scope` and the login does not go
>   through.
>
> I am able to use the same live credentials successfully otherwise.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/43686133/1219543

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with the Go Live process which is now resolved. Please try again.